# If $g(x)$ is continuous and $g(x)\geq0$ for all $x > 0$ then $g(0)\geq0$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Determine whether each statement is true or false. If true, provide a proof. If false, provide a counterexample.

(a) If $g(x)$ is continuous and $g(x)>0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ then $g(x)>0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

(b) If $g(x)$ is continuous and $g(x)\geq0$ for all $x > 0$ then $g(0)\geq0$.

Comment: I already proved a different problem that is basically the first statement but with g(x)=0 for all x in Q then g(x)=0 for all x in R. I am not sure how the greater than sign changes the situation, or if a similar proof would work.

Comment: Also, part b seems pretty self explanatory, so I am not sure how to prove it. Or are either of these problems false?

Answer (score 4):

For (b) use the definition of continuity for a sequence $x_n \to 0$ to talk about $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} g(x_n)$.

For (a), consider a "V"-shaped function $g$ centered at $\pi$ where $g(\pi)=0$. (For example, $g(x) = |x-\pi|$.) It is continuous everywhere, and strictly positive everywhere except at $x=\pi$.